# Stuck in the void. what is going on?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I was flying in creative and then I dug down below bedrock because I wanted to go back to spawn. In the past this kills a player but now you can "walk" on the void. In order to try to make it kill me, I switched to survival. (This is normally a survival map but I was on creative.) When I did that it did kill me but would not let me re-spawn, only go to the main menu. When I logged back in I was frozen with no hearts and did not have the death screen. After going in creative again, I got a black screen where I still am now. I have worked on this world for over a year and would really like to get it back. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: You might want to note which game you're playing.

Comment: You could try teleporting yourself back to your world "/tp current x pos, 83, current z pos"

Comment: Have you tried wiping your player data

Comment: Are you still flying? Try double tapping space

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear up any confusion, I know this is much better suited as a comment but I do not have enough reputation to comment yet. Sorry!

emansuperguy, just try /tp @p ~ ~100 ~

And as I said, I know this should be a comment but I can't comment yet.

Comment: More than that, someone actually wrote exactly this in a comment some 9 hours before you. Confusion not cleared.

Comment: Have you heard of Reputation On The Head? (Bounty)

Comment: Actually, what I said was partially different, and might possibly be easier to do as my way you don't need to look at your current coords. So Orc JMR, please actually think about what your'e saying before you say it. I know it is not my place to tell you this, but, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck and desperate to get out, there are a few solutions. These all work without the use of external programs.

1. `/kill`. This will kill you and teleport you to your spawnpoint. If you have your inventory perfectly organized, or you don't want to lose your items, there is always the `/gamerule keepInventory true` Command.
2. Double tap space. As @Uniforms For Sale said in the comments, you are most likely flying, and if so, this will kill you.
3. Go to `/gamemode sp.` This lets you phase through blocks.
4. Fly upwards and destroy blocks above you. If you don't know which way is up, use `F3` Or `FN-F3` For the debug screen, which should show coordinates. The 'Y' coordinates are the ones you should focus on, and if you are truly in the void, they should be negative. Work your way up to 0, bedrock, via flying.
5. `/tp @p ~ ~ ~`. As @onewho said in the comments, this can teleport you to the surface. Replace the ~s with the coordinates of where you want to teleport to, and hit enter. If you don't know what the coordinates of the place you want to be is, bring up the debug screen, and teleport to where you are now, but with the Y coordinate changed to at least 64.

   This will get you out of the void, but I recommend teleporting up to 100. Understanding that you have probably moved since you entered the void, this will bring you past the tallest mountains.